# Exporting filtered Excel table with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, export

**Python 3.4.3 | Anaconda 2.3 | Pandas**

I have filtered some data from an extensive excel. I have it running for two names:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys


#file loc
R1 = input('Data do Relatório desejado  (dd.mm) --->  ')
loc = r'C:\Users\lucas.mascia\Downloads\relatorio-{0}.xlsx'.format(R1)

######################################################################

#Solicitantes
ps_sol = ["Mauro Cavalheiro Junior", "Aline Oliveira"]


#Aplicando filtros
for name in ps_sol:

    #opening file
    df = pd.read_excel(loc)
    dfps = df[[2,15,16,17]]

    #apply filter
    f1 = dfps[(dfps['Cliente']=="POSTAL SAUDE")
        & (dfps['Nome do solicitante']==name)]

    #print info
    print ('''
    =============================================================
    Relatorio do dia:   {}
    Cliente:            POSTAL SAUDE
    Solicitante:        {}
    =============================================================
    '''.format(R1, name))

    print (f1)

    f1.to_excel('C:/Users/lucas.mascia/Downloads/ps_sol.xlsx', sheet_name=name)
```

At the end I am trying to export to another .xlsx file. But it is only saving the info of the last name in the list.

I want it to save for all names that i list in my ps_sol

Help please (: